# Reading postgis geometry with shapely

Tags: python, postgis, shapely

I am doing a small-scale workflow in ipython notebook with geopandas and shapely, pulling a bunch of geospatial data, sometimes from shapefiles, sometimes from postgis (where more expensive processing is performed).

Now, I then pull the postgis tables into python using `sqlalchemy`, transforming the geometry to WKT along the way, getting something like:

```
sql = """
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326)) as newgeom,* 
  FROM public.parcels2010_small limit 5;
 """
parcels = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
parcels

+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | newgeom                                           | the_geom                                          | parcel_id | osm_node_id |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| 0  | MULTIPOLYGON(((-122.991093691444 38.4878691106... | 01060000209C0E00000100000001030000000100000097... | 1805792   | 66237       |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| 1  | MULTIPOLYGON(((-122.444576448624 37.7346386006... | 01060000209C0E0000010000000103000000010000008A... | 10435     | 123826      |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| 2  | MULTIPOLYGON(((-122.796785208193 38.5427593334... | 01060000209C0E0000010000000103000000010000007D... | 1817842   | 313047      |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| 3  | MULTIPOLYGON(((-122.695538506163 38.3618570798... | 01060000209C0E0000010000000103000000010000009B... | 1934612   | 63776       |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| 4  | MULTIPOLYGON(((-122.223424422869 37.8416019090... | 01060000209C0E00000100000001030000000100000072... | 861785    | 26369       |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

This looks a lot like the geometry when loaded from a shapefile, but it is not cast as a shapely geometry. I couldn't find the canonical way to do it, either using shapely alone, or perhaps with `Descartes`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GeoAlchemy understands [SQLAlchemy PostGIS and Shapely](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.4/shape.html).

```
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape

for parcel in parcels:
    parcel_shape = to_shape(parcel.the_geom)
```

Answer (score 31):

The default format for PostGIS geometry is hex-encoded WKB (Well-Known Binary).  Shapely has the ability to convert this format into `shapely` geometry object with its `wkb` module:

```py
from shapely import wkb

# ....

sql = """SELECT * FROM public.parcels2010_small LIMIT 5;"""
parcels = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)

for parcel in parcels:
    parcel.the_geom = wkb.loads(parcel.the_geom, hex=True)
```

if you were to then print the geometry  it should look something like this:

```py
print parcels[0].the_geom

<shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon object at ...>
```

See docs on the shapely.wkb module [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=wkb#well-known-formats).

Comment: For more convenience, `geopandas` also offers a Series constructor [`GeoSeries.from_wkb`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkb.html#geopandas-geoseries-from-wkb) (or `from_wkt`) from a list of WKB (or WKT) objects. (It very likely uses `shapely.wkb` under the hood).